# How to use mlflow.evaluate() function with PTBXL data, which has a 3D array as input for a multiclass classification problem?

Tags: machine-learning, mlflow

I'm working on a multiclass classification problem with 5 classes using the PTBXL dataset, which has a 3D tensor shape of (21837, 12, 5000). Each sample has 12 leads, and each lead has 5000 time steps. I want to use mlflow.evaluate() function to evaluate my model, but it requires the data input to be a 2D numpy array or data frame, which is not the case with PTBXL.

I've seen an example (https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/master/examples/evaluation/evaluate_on_multiclass_classifier.py) of using mlflow.evaluate() function for a similar problem, but the input array was 2D, not 3D like in my case.

I don't want to reshape the array as it would require changing my model since it expects an input with 12 channels. Is there any way to use mlflow.evaluate() function with the PTBXL data without reshaping the array? Also my labels have 5 columns where each column has ane "1" for each row and the rest is "0". This also doesn't go well with the mlflow.evaulate() since it has to be 1D, but If I reshape I would need to change my model.

Is there any way to input my data and labels with dimensions of (2000,1000,12) and (2000,5) in mlflow.evaluate() without reshaping?.
Here's an example of how I'm currently loading and processing the data, which gives me an error:

```
test_signals = np.array(signals[dataset.strat_fold == 10])
test_labels = np.array(labels[dataset.strat_fold == 10])


test_labels2=np.argmax(test_labels, axis=1)
test_signals_reshaped = test_signals.reshape((test_signals.shape[0],test_signals.shape[1]*test_signals.shape[2]))


with mlflow.start_run(experiment_id=24) as run:

    # Evaluate the logged model
    result = mlflow.evaluate(
        model_uri,
        data=test_signals_reshaped,
        targets=test_labels2,
        model_type="classifier",
        evaluators=["default"],
    )
```